# Docusign Integration with my application with single sign on process

Tags: docusignapi

Our web application procedure is like

The docusign account user needs to use his/her own credentials to log in our application and can see the documents in our application sent him by our client.

For this how can we proceed with docusign . 
any procedure with restapi will be helpful for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is a common workflow- you need to use OAuth which let's you accomplish this in a secure way so that your application never sees the user's account credentials (instead it gets a valid access token to use on their behalf).

Since you have a web app you should use the Authorization Code Grant flow, the steps for Auth Code grant are:

1. Request the Authorization Code
2. Obtain the Access Token
3. Retrieve User Account Data

**NOTES**

In Step #1 your app needs to construct the proper authorization URI including query parameters and direct the user there so they can sign in using the standard DocuSign login. Once the user logs in and grants consent they are redirected back to your app along with an `authorization code` as a query parameter.

In Step #2 you use the `authorization code` retrieved from the first step to exchange for an access token.  This is an actual API call (as opposed to simply redirecting the user like step 1).

Step #3 is another API call your app needs to make to finally get the user's account data and `base_uri` where you can then start making requests on their behalf.

---

For more info see the following guide from the DS Dev Center:

[Authorization Code Grant](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-code-grant)

Comment: The redirect_uri is not redirecting correctly it is going in to the app.docusign.com/home page .. i am using the step1 like 
https://account.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id=&redirect_uri=https://www.lji.io

Comment: You need to configure one or more Redirect URIs on your Integrator Key through your sandbox admin menu.  Then in step #1 make sure you pass the same exact Redirect URI as one you have configured on your key and it will redirect the user to that URI once they have granted consent.

Comment: thank you for your valuable response . Can you please tell me that after using this url https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=fb8c8e5c-7573-43e3-a9ba-285319f105cd&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/" it is again going into the docusign login page , but i thought it will directly go in to grant consent . Is it possible for skip the login page of docusign and get the authorization code?

Comment: That is the correct functionality, the user needs to login to their account first THEN grant the consent.  Otherwise, you can have strangers granting consent for someone else's account without authenticating first.

Comment: trial version credentials to log in is giving me the invalid username or password error ? why this will happen ?

Comment: Could you tell me that which oauth flow i need to use to process work flow like the user fills the form and on submitting the form he will get the document for sign.

Comment: You can use any of the OAuth methods for this.  The OAuth flows are used to authenticate the SENDING user, the person who ends up filling out the form and signing the document simply receives the email notification to start the signing process.  For more info see the authentication overview guide:  https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication